# $(.'class-name').click(function() {...}) ceases to function cross-browser?

Tags: javascript, plunker

I'm uploading code from my project to Plunker. You can see it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/2xCVsWXFE7EqNlkdUJUc?p=preview). When I run the code through a local server and render it in Chrome, the functionality works fine. When I try to run it through Plunker the code fails.

This snippet is inside of `script.js`:

```
$('.navbar-toggle').click(function(){

  alert('test1');

    if ($(this).hasClass('login')) {
        $('.navmenu-style1').css("z-index","1");
        $('.navmenu-style').css("z-index","0"); 
    }
    else {
        $('.navmenu-style1').css("z-index","0");
        $('.navmenu-style').css("z-index","1");
    }
});
```

How can I make it work in Plunker please? Is there a more universal bit of code that I can use or am I simply doing something wrong?

Cheers

Comment: Have you tried fixing the HTML syntax error on line 90?

Comment: @amphetamachine Yes. That doesn't seem to have anything to do with my .js issue.

Comment: Did you look at the console? You have two errors both with links to the angular error docs for more information. This seems to be the main one: [`Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod]`](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/nomod?p0=sparkr)

Comment: I recommend to read the **jQuery tutorial** to learn how to use jQuery properly: http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have made one of the most common mistakes anyone makes when using JQuery. You tried to attach a click handler to a DOM object before the DOM was loaded:

```
<html>
<head>
...
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

contents of script.js:

```
$('.navbar-toggle').click(function(){ ... });
```

You have to wait for the DOM to load before you run that code. Like so:

```
$(function () {
    $('.navbar-toggle').click(function(){ ... });
});
```

Note: `$(function)` is just a shortcut for `$(document).ready(function)`.

Comment: The click even works in Chrome

Comment: I know, it must have won the race condition because it had to execute Angular and all those other libs before it executed script.js.